# AD9361: how to compute datarate and configure filters

Tags: fpga, filter, data-rate

I will use [AD9361](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad9361.pdf) as a transmitter of a modulated baseband signal. The modulated baseband signal is implemented in FPGA/SDK.

AD9361 has real-time bandwidth of 56MHz but we have maximum 61.44 MSPS data rate even if 1RX1TX is used.

This is obviously the maximum data rate at the I/O port of the AD9361. What does that mean for the actual data rates of the signal to be sent?

Which data rate would be achievable ?

Comment: AD9361 has a maximum ANALOG bandwidth of 56 MHz.  So, while you can clock data at a higher rate the signal will be limited by the analog bandwidth of the transceiver.